# PDF generation issue

Tags: pdftex, pdf, texlive

I am using LaTeX inside a Docker container to generate a PDF. As per the result the PDF generates successfully. But making targets did not complete. The error is as below.

[image]

My dockerFile is as follows.

```
FROM python:3
ADD pdf-generator.py /
RUN pip install boto3
RUN pip install sqs-polling
RUN pip install PyMySQL
RUN pip install PyLaTeX
RUN pip install pdflatex
# RUN pip install latexmk.py

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    texlive-full \
    biber \
    latexmk \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD [ "python","-u","./pdf-generator.py" ]
```

My code is as follows.

```
with open(texFile) as file:
    tex= file.read()
# Generate PDF here
doc = Document('output')
doc.append(NoEscape(tex))
doc.packages.append(Package('graphicx'))
doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: well you have at least one error in your code, see  the "\end occured inside a group" message.

Comment: What is the content of `output.tex`?  Just after the "end occurred inside a group" error message, it tells you that you entered that group at line 29 of some file.  What happens at line 29?  Or does output.tex include other files?